# Can I successfully run a Kali Linux VM on one drive while my host OS is on another?

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, partitioning, ssd, kali-linux

I've been attempting to set up a Kali Linux VM. I've continuously been running into a failure when attempting to install the system files inside VirtualBox and I'm curious as to whether or not it has anything to do with my drive set up.

My host OS (Win10) is located on my ssd (c:) while (almost) everything else on my system resides on my hdd (d:). I plan to run any VMs on my d:\ space and hoped to discover how to accomplish this as is or if I need to do something else.

My disk set up is as follows and I'm attempting to use the most current VirtualBox as well as Kali Linux.

[image]

Comment: I'll comment as i don't have the hard facts ATM, It's completely dependant on how you config your VM software, meaning you can store that image wherever in accordance with your VM software's config options, Usually i run vm in a window and keep my images @ C:\stuff

Comment: Unless Windows 10's VirtualBox has some bug I don't know about, it should let you specify where you want your virtual machine files, and if its in a separate disk or not is completely irrelevant as the VM itself isn't even aware of how the host system is storing it.

Comment: What errors specifically are you getting in virtual box?